# React State doesn't update inside function but everywhere else?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I have a problem, I've been stuck on for a couple of hours. My state doesn't get updated inside a function. As you can see in my example I have a `useState` hook which is responsible for keeping the value of the text input. Let's say I type in 'abcd', if i console log the state in the `handleChange` and outside of it just before return, the state shows correctly, however on the `handleHeaderRightButtonPress` which is responsible for the saving functionality basically, it doesn't update, it's always my default value, in this case `randomVal`. Any ideeas why this behaviour could happen or how could i troubleshoot it? Thanks in advance:

My example(I stripped out unnecessary code so it's easier)

```
const TextAreaScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const placeholder = route.params?.placeholder;
  const [value, setValue] = useState('randomval');

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: route.params?.title,
      headerRight: () =>
            <NavigationHeader.TextButton
              label={t('general.done')}
              onPress={handleHeaderRightButtonPress}
            />
    });
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (value: string) => {
    console.log('here', value); //the updated value shows up correctly
    setValue(value);
  };

  const handleHeaderRightButtonPress = () => {
    const onFinish = route.params?.onFinish;
    console.log('value in handleFunc', value); // the updated values does NOT work here
    onFinish(value);
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  console.log('state val::', value); // updated value shows up correctly
  return (
    <TextArea
      value={value}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChangeText={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default TextAreaScreen;
```

Comment: Can you show what your `onFinish` do?

Comment: it's coming via the route prop as a paramater: `onFinish: formikProps.handleChange('description')`

Comment: You enclosed the value of `value` from when the component mounted, thus all callbacks also enclosed at that time will reference state from the same render cycle they are enclosed in. When `value` updates you need to re-enclose its value in a new callback in the effect by adding it to the effect's dependency array. Basically your question is how to fix/address stale state.

Answer (score 0):

Pass value to useEffect like :

```
useEffect(() => {
navigation.setOptions({
  title: route.params?.title,
  headerRight: () =>
        <NavigationHeader.TextButton
          label={t('general.done')}
          onPress={handleHeaderRightButtonPress}
        />
});
```

}, [value]);

Answer (score -2):

Just noticed I wasn't updating my useEffect with the value. Fixed by adding it as a dependency in the array:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: route.params?.title,
      headerLeft: () => {
        const onBackPress = () => {
          navigation.goBack();
        };
        return Platform.select({
          ios: (
            <NavigationHeader.TextButton
              label={t('general.cancel')}
              onPress={onBackPress}
            />
          ),
          android: (
            <NavigationHeader.IconButton
              iconName="times"
              label={t('general.cancel')}
              onPress={onBackPress}
            />
          )
        });
      },
      headerRight: () =>
        Platform.select({
          ios: (
            <NavigationHeader.TextButton
              label={t('general.done')}
              onPress={handleHeaderRightButtonPress}
            />
          ),
          android: (
            <NavigationHeader.IconButton
              iconName="check"
              label={t('general.done')}
              onPress={handleHeaderRightButtonPress}
            />
          )
        })
    });
  }, [value]); // here
```